# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable with Python

Tags: python

I have this slice of Python code:

```
print(curr, nxt)
print (type(curr), type(nxt))
print (type(curr[0]), type(curr[1]))
print (type(nxt[0]), type(nxt[1]))

curr[0] = min(curr[0], nxt[0])
curr[1] = max(curr[1], nxt[1])
del condensed[i+1]
```

But when I run it, I get this output:

```
[3, 5] [4, 8] 
<class 'list'> <class 'list'> 
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> 
<class 'int'> <class 'int'> 

---> curr[1] = max(curr[1], nxt[1]) 

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong, it seems like all the inputs to `max()` is fine. Furthermore, it never gets an error with `min()`. Any ideas?

If anyone wants to see the full code, it's [on github](https://github.com/joshualan/Python-Problems/blob/master/InterviewCake4.py) and it's to solve [this problem](https://www.interviewcake.com/question/python/merging-ranges).

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another local (or even global) variable called `max`?

Comment: @Kupiakos you are a life-saver. That's totally it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a local or global variable called `max`. Therefore, Python was trying to use `max` (which was an integer) as a function.

Comment: Yup, that's totally it! Thanks, I always need help to figure out why I'm an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer! I had `max` set as a variable somewhere else in that function, causing the namespace to be all messed up!

Comment: Please don't post commentary as an answer.  If you do want to post this as an answer, edit it to look like one.

Comment: Done, thanks for the advice.